# static properties in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, properties, static

if I declare a properties like this in Silverlight

```
public static string Text{get;set;}
```

its value is share between users?
or it is created only on the client?
If a user change its value is changed for all the users?

If I use static properties or App.cs properties like this:

```
public static string Text{get;set;}
```

and call in my page like this:

```
(App.Current as MyNameSpace.App).MyPublicProperty
```

It's the same?
Which is the best?

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight app is app package, which is downloaded to client and executed as regular desktop app with some restrictions and browser integration.

It means even if you`ll run 2 copies of your app, each of them will be separated from another.

So everything in your app which is not sent to server is local.

Static variables are shared across local application.